# How to prevent blocked by JSON.stringify in nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js, stringify

I wrote some socket based server application which accept JSON data from many clients.
When I export large(over 20mb) data to file after JSON.stringify, application was blocked during the stringify operation.
So, I want to prevent blocking by JSON.stringify.
Is there any library do stringify without blocking? or how to figure out?

Comment: Maybe use a worker or fork a new process or something? Also, in your case it sounds all clear, but it's always good to provide some code example, even if it's an obvious one-liner.

Comment: Thx. I read about 'cluster' on node js. I'll try loadbalance on quad-core machine.

Comment: Cluster is good, but it's still blocking. What I meant is to use web worker - take a look at the sample implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are npm modules that offer asynchronous JSON APIs. See for example:

- [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream), which has stream APIs.
- [Big-Friendly JSON](https://github.com/philbooth/bfj), which has stream APIs as well as asynchronous
  versions of the standard JSON APIs using the
  partitioning-on-the-Event-Loop paradigm outlined below.

*Reference*: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/#blocking-the-event-loop-json-dos